# tchart in delphi remove text over each bar

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am using a tchart in Delphi. It is a bar chart, and to add to each series, it requires 3 parameters like this:

```
chart1.series[0].add(123,'annoying',clred);
```

The middle parameter, in this example the word "annoying" results in that string being displayed over the bar.

Is there a way to create a bar chart without having the string appear? The obvious thing was to use an empty value , like `...add(123,'',clred)` but it still draws this over the bar with what looks like random numbers in each series.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem showing random numbers in the marks. Could you please arrange an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

TBarSeries.Add has one-parameter overloaded version

Anyway, you can off showing of string labels:

In chart editor, in Object Inspector, in the code: `Series-Marks-Visible`

```
//Series1-General-BottomAxis-DataTime is set
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Series1.Marks.Visible := false;
  for i := -2 to 0 do
     Series1.AddXY(Now + 3 * i, i + 3);
```

Comment: I tried it and the label over the bar disappeared. I unchecked it and tried again, as reported above like ..series[0].add(amt,' ',clred) and the random numbers went away, and it is now displaying the numeric value of the variable "amt". But now I need to add a similar label below the bar, a string representation of a date in the mm/dd/yy format.

Comment: continuaton. .... I could not find anything in reference on steema.com. I do not want to try to do this in the chart editor, because the dates are not known until runtime, as it is pulling the last 5 pay raise amount and dates fro a database. I am looking for something along the lines of chart1[0].bottom_label := raise_date but there is no such property like this,  How, then, can you set this bottom label string at runtime, using Delphi code?

Comment: I found a way to populate the bottom labels and it works, but in doing so , it also overwrites the top labels, wiping out the raise amount with the same date value that appears on the bottom.

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand your needs. Look at example

Comment: If you drop a Tchart on a Delphi form of a new projet, add 1 series of type Bar,  and add 2 buttons, I think you will see the problem.

Comment: continuation - 
Run the program and button 1 displays the amount over the top of each bar, and a sequential number under the bar. Button2 displays the Day of the week on the top and the bottom (the axis?). I want the amount on the top and the day under the bar. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you believe that I use telepathy? Show your code. Anyway, your question has been answered, and perhaps you  have to make new question with clear description.

Comment: @SteveL Please, when you are asked for additional information, edit your question (see the *edit* button just beneath the tags?). All relevant information must be added to the question itself.